# Failing Eval.me searches for the field not in the class it is in

Tags: parsing, gradle, groovy, eval

I am trying to read a value ov a variable with parsed name:

```
class GatewayFunctionBuilder{
    private String responseClass
    .....
    String target = 'esponse'
    println "writing r${target}Class"
    println responseClass
    String targetClass = Eval.me("r${target}Class")
```

The result is:

```
writing responseClass
MWFtest0A1Response
:application:generateJavaFromTestMwf FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'C:\Users\543829657\workspace\dev.appl.ib.cbl\application\Xml2Java.gradle' line: 53

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':application:generateJavaFromTestMwf'.
> No such property: responseClass for class: Script1
```

The content of the printed variables is correct. But it seems, Eval.me searches for the responseClass field not in the class it is called from, but from the Gradle task script.

If I pass the this object as a parameter, it works:

```
String targetClass = Eval.x(this, "x.r${target}Class")
```

But that has not any logic, for `this` is also not a field of the task script, but is something, that has correct sense only for an instance of that class. And even if that instance is created in the task script (as a local variable), it has other name there.

I see no mentions in Eval documentation, that it evaluates the string in the context of some "Script1"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code for `Eval` in Groovy 2.4.4 is [here](http://grepcode.com/file_/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.codehaus.groovy/groovy-all/2.4.4/groovy/util/Eval.java/?v=source). We observe the following:

```
class Eval { ...
public static Object me(final String expression) throws CompilationFailedException {
    return me(null, null, expression);
}
```

and:

```
 public static Object me(final String symbol, final Object object, final String expression) throws CompilationFailedException {
    Binding b = new Binding();
    b.setVariable(symbol, object);
    GroovyShell sh = new GroovyShell(b);
    return sh.evaluate(expression);
}
```

so the behaviour can be reproduced in pure Groovy, without Gradle:

```
// Eval.me(expression) == Eval.me(null, null, expression)
def symbol = null
def object = null
def responseClass = "hello"
def target = "esponse"
def expression = "r${target}Class"

def b = new Binding();
b.setVariable(symbol, object);
def sh = new GroovyShell(b);
println sh.evaluate(expression);
```

where it is clear that `expression` will not be found in the `Binding` object.

Comment: And why should the expression be in Binding? Binding holds external(system and user)  variables.

Comment: I see. As if eval() really only launches the GroovyShell.evaluate(), it has no knowledge of the class or instance it was called from. You have explained how the problem could happen. They simply made in in the most easy way. Easy for them, not for the user.